# 500 internal server error on linux web hosting server

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-hosting

Bought a linux web hosting server, uploaded my php files

Accessing www.domainname.com keeps on showing '500 internal server error'

No error logs are generated - tried including ini_set('display_errors',1); at start of every php page to show error messages, however, no error messages visible on the server and no log files generated

.htaccess file is blank.

Created phpinfo.php file as ..

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

..to see if php works, but no success, keeps on showing '500 internal server error'

Please let me know what can be done or where m i going wrong? thanks

Comment: When you say there are no error logs generated are you only referring to PHP errors?  Or are you including your nginx or apache logs as well?  How about your fcgi logs?  Are the permissions on the files you are trying to access correct and readable to the server daemon?  Any other information you can tell us about the services that are running would help.

Comment: is this in localhost?

Comment: Check whether rewrite module  enabled in your server?

Comment: Put some static files (like pure HTML) and try open them in browser, if you see the error again, there must be something wrong with Apache configuration. Check httpd.conf or .htaccess then.

Comment: @cjaredrun - there are no error logs under access_logs folder or any other path

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain - this is linux web hosting server purchased from godaddy

Comment: Backup your `.htaccess` file and remove it. Is the problem (500 Internal Server error) resolved? If yes: The problem is in your `.htaccess`. If not: The problem might be in `httpd.conf`. The fact that php doesn't generate errors, suggests that the php pages are never actually executed (e.g. Apache gives the error).

Comment: @balajimca - how to check whether rewrite module is enabled or not?

Comment: @Bhavik Try contacting GoDaddy about it

Comment: @ChiChou - able to use HTML files, but not php files

Comment: @Sumurai8 - htaccess file is blank. Also tried renaming htaccess file to a different name, it auto creates blank htaccess file when i access any php file on the server. unable to find httpd.conf file on the server. what should be the content of httpd.conf file?

Comment: @VarunAgw - Have dropped a message on godaddy forum yesterday, pending moderation

Comment: @Bhavik The `httpd.conf` file is the main configuration file. (I believe it is called `apache.conf` or `apache2.conf` in some cases). I would think GoDaddy would supply you with a working one if it is pre-delivered with Apache and you didn't touch it. Does the Apache default user have read-access on your files (e.g. does it start working if you change the rights on a file to 777, which you never should use btw)?

Comment: Under System Apache handlers I can see cgi-script handler with .cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl extensions and server-parsed handler with .shtml extension. Is it required to add handler for .php extension?

Comment: added handler application/x-httpd-php with .php extension, now when i access a php page (eg - www.domain.com/example.php), a prompt comes up asking to save the example.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Internal Server Error you can try these following things.

- Disable .htaccess file temporarily
- Check server Error Logs if contain something.
- In case the page is using PHP, check if there is no error in PHP.
- Check if web server has permission to access content. Also, confirm if you are using correct document root.

Comment: is there any way to disable .htaccess? tried renaming it to .htaccess_renamed, internal server error persists

Comment: Renaming it to something else is equivalent to disabling it. Try other steps too

Comment: > No error logs generated. One reason of this might be the server isn't actually executing PHP files. What can be done to resolve this?
> Page is using PHP, those PHP are working fine locally on my desktop with wampserver installed
> PHP files are having 644 permission, whereas folders are having 755 permission. All these files and folders are under /home/domainname/public_html/ folder

Comment: Removed all uploaded PHP files from the server and then removed htaccess file. Then executed HTML & PHP file one by one and came to know that htaccess file was corrupt. It wasnt required. Thanks everyone for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly for example on CPanel/WHM servers there is a case (suPHP configuration I think) when the permissions of the php files are checked. These should be 644. When you uploaded these might be 664 (group can write, while it shoudln't). And the result if the permissions are wrong was exactly error 500.
And the permissions of the folders should be 755 in this case.

Comment: Have PHP files with 644 permission and folders with 755 permission. But dont know if my server is suPHP configured or not. Is there any way to find out this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with godaddy.

How i fixed?

Installed WordPress using cpanel webapp installer. ".php" files worked fine there after.

Tried lot of other ways but failed. I think its problem with the hosting provider.